Announcing the September–October 2024 topic challenge: Svetlana Alexievich
In accordance with our meta agreement to have topic challenges
and a later meta agreement to have topic challenges lasting for two months and overlapping by one month,
it is time to announce the September–October 2024 topic challenge.
Based on the number of votes (+6), our next topic challenge will be
the works of Svetlana Alexievich

What's a topic challenge?
See the meta posts linked above, and also this main Meta post.
In short, during September and October 2024 you are invited to try to get hold of one or more of the works by Svetlana Alexievich, read them, and ask or answer questions about them.
Participation is not obligatory in any sense, and questions on other works are more than welcome during September and October too;
they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.
How can I take part?
By getting hold of one or more of the works by Svetlana Alexievich and

asking good questions about it or
answering questions that have been posted as part of this challenge or
submitting a book review to our Tumblr blog.

Questions about these works should be tagged svetlana-alexievich and russian-language (and a tag for any book-length work).
We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.
Below is EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine's
presentation:

Svetlana Alexievich is a Nobel Prize-winning Belarusian journalist and author. (While this is related to my proposal for Belarusian literature, my understanding is that her books were largely written in Russian, so they would likely fall outside of the scope of the previous proposal).
Several particularly well-known books by her include:

Zinky Boys: Soviet Voices from a Forgotten War (new translation from 2017: Boys in Zinc, published by Penguin);
Chernobyl Prayer / Voices from Chernobyl, available to borrow from the Internet Archive.


What's next?

Vote for the next topic challenge or propose your own!


List of all questions posted in this topic challenge

Were Soviet doctors and nurses actually as callous as "Voices from Chernobyl" portrays in the prologue? by EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine on 23/09/2024 (Hot Network Question, ca 6650 views, 16 votes, 3 answers).
Which part of the Bible supposedly talks of a leader with a mark on his forehead? by Tsundoku on 07/10/2024 (Hot Network Question, ca. 1470 views, 8 votes, 1 answer).
Where did Sergey Bulgakov write that the world cannot altogether fail? by Tsundoku on 15/10/2024 (ca. 60 views, 3 votes, 1 answer).
What was "the amnesty" that Voices from Chernobyl refers to? by EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine on 17/10/2024 (Hot Network Question, ca. 910 views, 3 votes, 1 answer).
Who wrote The Cleaners and what is the book about? by Tsundoku on 20/10/2024 (ca. 88 views, 3 votes, 1 answer).
Which part of the Bible supposedly prophesies a time when everything would be lush but man wouldn't be able to use any of it?  by Tsundoku on 21/10/2024 (ca. 112 views, 2 votes, 1 answer).
What differences are there between the two editions of "Voices from Chernobyl"? by 
Clara Díaz Sanchez on 25/10/2024 (ca. 31 views, 2 votes, no answer).
Where did Anna Akhmatova write, "Half of the country imprisoning, half of the country imprisoned"?  by Tsundoku on 30/10/2024 (Hot Network Question, ca. 842 views, 6 votes, 1 answer).


The highest-voted and most viewed of these is Were Soviet doctors and nurses actually as callous as "Voices from Chernobyl" portrays in the prologue?, with a score of 16 and approximately 6650 views by the end of October.
7 of 8 questions received at least one answer.
Four questions became Hot Network Questions (HNQ).

Reviews submitted to our Tumblr blog:

Chernobyl Prayer by Svetlana Alexievich, 31 October 2024, Tsundoku

